# How to synchronize deletions between Google Photos web and Android app?

Tags: google-photos

I have Google Photos syncing with my laptop and my phone Android app.

If I create photos on my Android Photos app, they are synced to the Photos website and to my laptop.

If I delete photos from my Android Photos app, the deletions are synced to the Photos website and to my laptop.

If I delete photos from my laptop, they are also deleted from the Photos website, which is good.  They are not deleted from the phone app, which is bad.  How do I get deletions to synchronize with the phone app?

(I look at the photos on the laptop with XnView to compare them side by side and delete the blurrier or otherwise inferior copy of the same photo.  I don't know what I'm going to do when they stop syncing with the laptop.)

Comment: this is an issue of synchronization in Android settings. it has nothing to do with google photos or your laptop

Comment: @user0 What do I need to change to make deletions sync the same way that additions sync?

Comment: Since yesterday, the system completely changed. Before that date, I would have said that in my experience, photos are indeed deleted from the Android app too, except that the cache from Google Photo is very slow to update, so some times it take a long time to see the effect. I have Google Photos on an Android and an iPhone, and I never see the same thing instantly. I have to wait.